# Google Big Query from Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to run a simple query on BigQuery from Python and follow [this](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html) document. To set the client I generated the JSON file for my project via [service account](http://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts):

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=*****
client = bigquery.Client()

QUERY = (
    'SELECT name FROM `mythic-music-326213.mytestdata.trainData` '
    'LIMIT 100')
query_job = client.query(QUERY)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

Technically, I want to be able to query my dataset from Python. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code snippet with my service account JSON file and dataset in my project. It worked as expected. Not clear why it's not working in your case.

Hovewer you can try to use service account JSON file directly like that:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('<path to JSON file>')
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

QUERY = (
    'SELECT state FROM `so-project-a.test.states` '
    'LIMIT 100')
query_job = client.query(QUERY)
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work for me. Do you know if there is any way to use api key or another way rather than using Jason file? It would be difficult to use Jason to get credential at production

Comment: @Amir the answer I've given was kind of workaround for one-off problem. In general Google Cloud recommends to avoid usage of user-managed service account keys like this JSON file, when possible. For example if you run your app on GCP VM you can just attach service account to the VM and there is no need in your code to use file or specify value for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable.
See recommendations https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-using-and-managing-service-accounts#choosing_when_to_use_service_accounts.